# Excel - Return the column which contain three specific value in specific rows

Tags: excel

I'm pulling my hair right now trying to achieve that without VBA. 
I do not want any VBA and I know It's easy to do with  barely more than two lines of vba code.

Here is a simplified template of the type of table I'm working with.

[image]

**The objective is** : With one formula Return the column where the three specified values are matched. The value Im searching for will be somewhere on the sheet where the formula will be. 
Just put them as value in the formula if you have one that can achieve that.

Best regards and thanks in advance if anyone help me restore my mental sanity.

Comment: What are the specified values? Will each column only have three values. Are some values repeated from column to column?

Comment: the three first rows have a large range of value they can take. Each individual value can be repeated many times. However each column have a unique set of the three value, no other column will have the three same.
I want a formula which return me the column (Letter or Index number) where the 3 value I'm searching for are present.

Comment: So... you're looking for `50`, `500`, and `500` as your three values, and the formula should return `3` indicating column C?

Comment: Not Realy. If I were to search for values it would be that. However It's the column name i'm searching for. The values 10;100;1000 & 50;500;500 are juste placeholders. same as the row names A;B;C.
I want to find the column where the three first rows values are KPI A; DATE; DATA TYPE.
And that with a formula, no VBA.

Comment: I know that, but *using your provided sample data* what is an *example* of what you're searching for and it's expected result?  So back to my question, is one of the possibilities you'd be looking for be `50`, `500`, and `500`?  And if so, would the expected result be `3`?

Comment: Example : Search for KPI A; DATE; DATA TYPE --> Return column 2.
Example 2 : Search for KPI B; DATE; DATA TYPE --> Return column 3.

Basicaly you had it right except i'm searching for the column "name". Sorry if my edit made it complicated to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a data setup like this:

[image]

This formula is in cell F1:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:C1&B2:C2&B3:C3=F2&F3&F4)*(COLUMN(B1:C1)))
```

Adjust ranges to suit your actual data

Explanation:

- It combines values of the columns' rows into a single string (so in this example, it would be {"KPI ADATEDATA TYPE","KPI BDATEDATA TYPE"})
- It then compares those results to a combined string of what you're looking for: "KPI ADATEDATA TYPE" converts results to TRUE/FALSE so  you end up with {TRUE,FALSE} (because the first combined string with KPI A matches)
- Then it gets all possible column numbers of the results: {2,3} in this case for columns B and C
- The multiplication then converts the TRUE/FALSE's into 1s and 0s respectively so you end up with {1,0}*{2,3}
- Because there can assumably only be a single match, this results in the correct column number being the only value to be multiplied by 1, so results are {2,0}
- The SUMPRODUCT then sums the results, and since there is only a single non-zero number, it must be the column index.

Comment: Brilliant. Exactly what I was looking for. 
It will adapt perfectly to my set of data.

Comment: Hey i'm comming back. 
It works perfeclty, too perfeclty.To the point I feel dumb not being sure to understand how it works. Would you mind explaining a bit ? what's the trick there ?

Comment: @BobRkt Edited answer to include an explanation.

Comment: Very clever. I had no idea SUMPRODUCT worked that way. Does it only act this way when fed with a matrix declared that way or Is is the true/false that triggers the conversion into string ? both required ?  Why does it concatenate the column's rows together and not the range you declare? 

I hope that's not too much questions haha.

Comment: Sumproduct is what forces the inside functions to act as an array formula.  You could achieve the same effect with Sum, but you'd have to confirm it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just Enter like normal.  See here for more about array formulas: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d

Comment: As for why it concats the column's rows and not the declared range, is also because of how array formulas are handled.  Excel sees each cell within the range as its own element, and aligns individual elements together first instead of parent ranges first.

Comment: Ahh, it's relieving to eventualy fully understand. thanks !